# How do I download a file over an authenticated url in iOS?

Tags: ios, authentication, download, nsurlconnection, nsdata

I'm using NSURLConnection to authenticate over https, which works fine, but when downloading a file using NSData, I'm unable to access the content. How do I download a file over an authenticated url?

**Here's where I'm trying to read the contents of the downloaded file (authentication code not included here), the server says "user not authorized":**

```
- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveData:(NSData *)data {

 NSFileManager *fileManager = [NSFileManager defaultManager];

            // Attempt to open the file and write the downloaded data to it
          if (![fileManager fileExistsAtPath:documentsDirectory2]) { //download path
                [fileManager createFileAtPath:documentsDirectory2 contents:nil attributes:nil];
            }
            // Append data to end of file
            NSFileHandle *fileHandle = [NSFileHandle fileHandleForWritingAtPath:documentsDirectory2];
            [fileHandle seekToEndOfFile];
            [fileHandle writeData:data];
            [fileHandle closeFile];



            //data.txt exists, read me its content
            NSArray *paths8 = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
            NSString *documentsDirectory8 = [paths8 objectAtIndex:0];
            NSString *filePath8 = [documentsDirectory8 stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"data.txt"];
            NSString *content8 = [NSString stringWithContentsOfFile:filePath8 encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:NULL];
            NSLog(@"WHATS INSIDE DATA.TXT? =%@", content8);

            [self.responseData appendData:data];
           }
```

Comment: sure, it's been updated.

Comment: If your error is `user not authorized` then maybe you should include your authentication code....

Comment: Inafziger, authentication works via nsurlconnection boilerplate code to read urls, but just not reading downloaded files.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use NSURLCredential to authenticate while implementing the NSURLConnectionDelegate.

Heres a example:

```c
-(BOOL)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection canAuthenticateAgainstProtectionSpace:(NSURLProtectionSpace *)protectionSpace
{
    return YES;
}

-(void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveAuthenticationChallenge:(NSURLAuthenticationChallenge *)challenge
{
    NSURLCredential *credential = [NSURLCredential credentialWithUser:username
                                                             password:passwd]
                                                             persistence:NSURLCredentialPersistenceForSession];

    [[challenge sender] useCredential:credential forAuthenticationChallenge:challenge];
}
```

Comment: Alexandresoli, I updated the question and omitted the nsurlcredential code in the example above for clarity. Authentication works fine when reading json files, but if I want to download a different file type (say, an mp4), I'm unable to access it.

Comment: Try to check the permissions in the server, if you can access the file from your browser the code should work.

Comment: The thing is, the file is not accessible through the browser because it requires a username/password for authentication.